# Changing URL .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

From this:
http://ice-phoenix.dx.am/jlpt/form/try_question.php

To This:
http://ice-phoenix.dx.am/jlpt/try_question

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^jlpt/form/try_question\.php$ jlpt/try_question/ [L]
```

Can any help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You're thinking the wrong way round: the URL requested by the browser is what you need to match, and the one to serve instead is the rule output. In other words, mod_rewrite doesn't make ugly URLs pretty, it makes pretty URLs act like they were ugly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm sorry but I don't get it. Is the url I wnat is  not possible?

Comment: You have the arguments to RewriteRule the wrong way round, basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Root/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /jlpt/form/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /jlpt/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^jlpt/([^/]+)/?$ /jlpt/form/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Why are you testing `THE_REQUEST` in that first rule, rather than just `RewriteRule /jlpt/form/([^.]+)\.php /jlpt/$1? [R,L]`?

Comment: That is to redirect ugly to preety url, otherwise without that condition RewriteRule would not work.

Comment: @Starkeen I understand what the rule is for, but not why it needs to be broken into two lines. What is wrong with the straight-forward rule in my comment?